# Waiting on multiple async's reliably?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, concurrency

My code needs to fire multiple threads and keep track of which have finished and which are still running. I as planning on using `waitAny` or `waitAnyCatch`, but was thrown off by the following in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:waitAny)

> If multiple Asyncs complete or have completed, then the value returned corresponds to the first completed Async in the list.

If that is *really* the case, how does one ever keep track of running / exited threads reliably?

Here's my simplified code:

```
chan <- newChan
currentThreadsRef <- newIORef []

-- read jobs from a channel, and run them in parallel asyncs/threads,
-- while adding all threads references to currentThreadsRef
async $ do
  jobArgs <- readChan chan
  jobAsync <- async $ runJob jobArgs
  atomicallyModifyIORef' currentThreadsRef $ \x -> (jobAsync:x, ())

-- wait for jobs to be finished, and remove the thread refernece
-- from currentThreadsRef 
waitForAllJobs currentJobsRef = do
  (readIORef currentJobsRef) >>= \case
    [] -> logDebug "All jobs exited"
    currentJobs -> do
      (exitedJob, jobResult) <- waitAnyCatch currentJobs
      atomicallyModifyIORef currentJobsRef $ \x -> (filter (/= exitedjob) x, ())
      logDebug $ "Job completed with result=" <> show result
      waitForAllJobs currentJobsRef
```

PS: Although it may not be obvious from my simplified code above, there is a reason why I cannot simply use `mapConcurrently` over the input-data. Actually, [`async-pool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-pool-0.9.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async-Pool.html) seems like a good fit for my use-case, but even that has the same problem with `waitAny`.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. `waitAny` returns one of the completed ones (what else would you like it to do?), and you remove it from the list. Then you recurse. As long as no one else is writing on `currentJobsRef` when `waitForAllJobs` is run, I can't spot any reason why this should be unreliable. (Note: I'm not very familiar with `async`)

Comment: "PS: Although it may not be obvious from my simplified code above, there is a reason why I cannot simply use `mapConcurrently` over the input-data." Can you explain what that reason is?

Comment: @chi yes, you are right. I didn't realize if any `Async` passed to `waithAny` has already exited, it is immediately going to report that, and the next iteration is going to pick up the others, one at a time.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica have a producer which is producing expensive jobs, where producing AND running the job, both, are expensive. We cannot produce all jobs all at once, and we cannot execute them all at once concurrently. The only solution that is possible with the standard `async` api is to produce the jobs in batches and run `mapConcurrently` over small batches. However, even that is inefficient because it waits for every job in a batch to complete before starting the next batch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a program that launches 1000 asyncs all set to terminate within a second and waits for them all in a loop.  Compiled with `ghc -O2 -threaded` and run with `+RTS -N`, it runs in about 1.5 seconds, and none of the asyncs gets "lost":

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import qualified Data.Set as Set

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let n = 1000 :: Int
  asyncs0 <- mapM (\i -> async (threadDelay 1000000 >> return i)) [1..n]
  let loop :: Set.Set (Async Int) -> IO ()
      loop asyncs | null asyncs = return ()
                  | otherwise = do
                      (a, _i) <- waitAny (Set.toList asyncs)
                      loop (Set.delete a asyncs)
  loop (Set.fromList asyncs0)
```

So, as was mentioned in a comment, the documentation is referring to the fact that the first completed async in the provided list is the one that will be "returned", but if multiple asyncs have completed, the additional ones aren't "forgotten".  You just need to remove the returned async from the list and re-poll, and you'll eventually get them all.

So, you shouldn't have any trouble waiting on multiple asyncs with `waitAny`.